# javanav bar from top of page to left side-updated

Tags: jquery, navigation

Does anyone know, where in the javacode I would edit to make the nav bar in this fiddle to go down the left side, instead of across the top? I want to retain the same properties that the bar has from the top.

https://jsfiddle.net/z9g6wwu6/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> 
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
        <title>Tab Styles Inspiration</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Tab Styles Inspiration: A small collection of styles for tabs" />
        <meta name="keywords" content="tabs, inspiration, web design, css, modern, effects, svg" />
        <meta name="author" content="Codrops" />


        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../favicon.ico">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/demo.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/tabs.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/tabstyles.css" />
        <script src="js/modernizr.custom.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div style="height: 100vh; width: 100vw">
        <div style="height:97%; width: 100%; border:2px yellow solid">
            <section>
                <div class="tabs tabs-style-iconbox" style=" border:2px blue solid; height:24em">
                    <nav>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#section-iconbox-1" class="icon icon-home"><span>Home</span></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#section-iconbox-2" class="icon icon-gift"><span>Deals</span></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#section-iconbox-3" class="icon icon-upload"><span>Local</span></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#section-iconbox-4" class="icon icon-coffee"><span>New York</span></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#section-iconbox-5" class="icon icon-config"><span>Genius</span></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#section-iconbox-5" class="icon icon-config"><span>Exclusives</span></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                    <div class="content-wrap">
                        <section id="section-iconbox-1" style="border:2px red solid; height: 17em"><p style="border:2px green solid; height: 3.9em"></p></section>
                        <section id="section-iconbox-2"><p>2</p></section>
                        <section id="section-iconbox-3"><p>3</p></section>
                        <section id="section-iconbox-4"><p>4</p></section>
                        <section id="section-iconbox-5"><p>5</p></section>
                    </div><!-- /content -->
                </div><!-- /tabs -->
            </section>

</div>
        </div><!-- /container -->
        <script src="js/cbpFWTabs.js"></script>
        <script>
            (function() {

                [].slice.call( document.querySelectorAll( '.tabs' ) ).forEach( function( el ) {
                    new CBPFWTabs( el );
                });

            })();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try ```flex-direction: row-reverse;```.

Comment: Thanks. Where would I add that?

Comment: Like for ```ul``` which have the style ```display: flex;```

Comment: Thanks. I think I misexplained. I am trying to have the navigation go down the left side of the page instead of across the top.

Comment: See this https://jsfiddle.net/aavrug/4bnhb1tf/ Use ```float: left;``` for ```nav``` and for ```ul``` ```flex-direction: column;``` and check for responsive styling.

Comment: This works wonderfully- thank you very much for the help!

Comment: After playing a little more, it seems that the flex direction has had some unexpected affects. Whats the best way to prevent the content from falling under the left side navigation when at resolutions under 1440x900? https://jsfiddle.net/qx8k3uuy/2/

Comment: I tried with a big screen but I didn't faced any issue.

Comment: on a big screen its great. Resolutions 1440 and under however dont work as well. The content sits under the nav bar. At a higher resolution, the content doesnt expand all the way despite 100%. I am not sure if the fiddle shows this since it cant pull the images, etc

Comment: It means you haven't written proper ```media-query``` styling.

Answer (score 0):

With a small tweak in your css `float: left;` for `nav` and for `ul` `flex-direction: column;` you can fix this.

```css
/* Individual tab styles */

/*****************************/
/* Bar */
/*****************************/

.tabs-style-bar nav {
 background: rgba(40,44,42,0.05);
}

.tabs-style-bar nav ul {
 border: 4px solid transparent;
}

.tabs-style-bar nav ul li a {
 margin: 0 2px;
 background-color: #f7f7f7;
 color: #74777b;
 transition: background-color 0.2s, color 0.2s;
}

.tabs-style-bar nav ul li a:hover,
.tabs-style-bar nav ul li a:focus {
 color: #2CC185;
}

.tabs-style-bar nav ul li a span {
 text-transform: uppercase;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
 font-weight: 500;
 font-size: 0.6em;
}

.tabs-style-bar nav ul li.tab-current a {
 background: #2CC185;
 color: #fff;
}

/*****************************/
/* Icon box */
/*****************************/

.tabs-style-iconbox nav {
 background: rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
}

.tabs-style-iconbox nav ul li a {
 overflow: visible;
 padding: 2em 0;
 line-height: 1;
 -webkit-transition: color 0.2s;
 transition: color 0.2s;
}

.tabs-style-iconbox nav ul li a span {
 font-weight: 700;
 font-size: 0.7em; 
}

.tabs-style-iconbox nav ul li.tab-current {
 z-index: 100;
}

.tabs-style-iconbox nav ul li.tab-current a {
 background: #fff;
 box-shadow: -1px 0 0 #fff;
}

.tabs-style-iconbox nav ul li.tab-current a::after {
 position: absolute;
 top: 100%;
 left: 50%;
 margin-left: -10px;
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 border: solid transparent;
 border-width: 10px;
 border-top-color: #fff;
 content: '';
 pointer-events: none;
}

.tabs-style-iconbox nav ul li:first-child::before,
.tabs-style-iconbox nav ul li::after {
 position: absolute;
 top: 20%;
 right: 0;
 z-index: -1;
 width: 1px;
 height: 60%;
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.07);
 content: '';
}

.tabs-style-iconbox nav ul li:first-child::before {
 right: auto;
 left: 0;
}

.tabs-style-iconbox .icon::before {
 display: block;
 margin: 0 0 0.25em 0;
}

/*****************************/
/* Underline */
/*****************************/

.tabs-style-underline nav {
 background: #fff;
}

.tabs-style-underline nav a {
 padding: 0.25em 0 0.5em;
 border-left: 1px solid #e7ecea;
 -webkit-transition: color 0.2s;
 transition: color 0.2s;
}

.tabs-style-underline nav li:last-child a {
 border-right: 1px solid #e7ecea;
}

.tabs-style-underline nav li a::after {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 6px;
 background: #2CC185;
 content: '';
 -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s;
 transition: transform 0.3s;
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,150%,0);
 transform: translate3d(0,150%,0);
}

.tabs-style-underline nav li.tab-current a::after {
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
 transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}

.tabs-style-underline nav a span {
 font-weight: 700;
}

/*****************************/
/* Top Line */
/*****************************/

.tabs-style-topline {
 max-width: 1200px;
}

.tabs-style-topline nav li {
 border: 1px solid rgba(40,44,42,0.1);
}

.tabs-style-topline nav li:not(:last-child) {
 border-right: none;
}

.tabs-style-topline nav li.tab-current {
 border-top-color: #2CC185;
 border-bottom: none;
}

.tabs-style-topline nav a {
 padding: 0.65em 0 0.5em;
 background: rgba(40,44,42,0.05);
 color: #74777b;
 line-height: 1;
 -webkit-transition: color 0.2s;
 transition: color 0.2s;
}

.tabs-style-topline nav a:hover,
.tabs-style-topline nav a:focus {
 color: #2CC185;
}

.tabs-style-topline nav li.tab-current a {
 background: none;
 box-shadow: inset 0 3px 0 #2CC185;
 color: #2CC185;
}

.tabs-style-topline .icon::before {
 display: block;
 margin: 0;
}

.tabs-style-topline nav a span {
 text-transform: uppercase;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
 font-weight: 700;
 font-size: 0.5em;
}

/*****************************/
/* Falling Icon, from http://vintageproductions.eu/grid/interactivity/ */ 
/*****************************/

.tabs-style-iconfall {
 overflow: visible;
}

.tabs-style-iconfall nav a {
 display: inline-block;
 overflow: visible;
 padding: 1em 0 2em;
 color: #74777b;
 line-height: 1;
 -webkit-transition: color 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.7,0,0.3,1); 
 transition: color 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.7,0,0.3,1);
}

.tabs-style-iconfall nav a:hover,
.tabs-style-iconfall nav a:focus,
.tabs-style-iconfall nav li.tab-current a {
 color: #2CC185;
}

.tabs-style-iconfall nav a span {
 font-weight: 700;
}

.tabs-style-iconfall nav li::before {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 1em;
 left: 50%;
 margin-left: -20px;
 width: 40px;
 height: 4px;
 background: #2CC185;
 content: '';
 opacity: 0;
 -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.2s ease-in;
 transition: transform 0.2s ease-in;
 -webkit-transform: scale3d(0,1,1);
 transform: scale3d(0,1,1);
}

.tabs-style-iconfall nav li.tab-current::before {
 opacity: 1;
 -webkit-transform: scale3d(1,1,1);
 transform: scale3d(1,1,1);
}

.tabs-style-iconfall .icon::before {
 display: block;
 margin: 0 0 0.35em;
 opacity: 0;
 -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.2s, opacity 0.2s;
 transition: transform 0.2s, opacity 0.2s;
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,-100px,0);
 transform: translate3d(0,-100px,0);
 pointer-events: none;
}

.tabs-style-iconfall nav li.tab-current .icon::before {
 opacity: 1;
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
 transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 58em) {
 .tabs-style-iconfall nav li .icon::before {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
 }
}

/*****************************/
/* Moving Line */
/*****************************/

.tabs-style-linemove nav {
 background: #fff;
}

.tabs-style-linemove nav li:last-child::before {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 4px;
 background: #2CC185;
 content: '';
 -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s;
 transition: transform 0.3s;
}

/* Move the line */
.tabs-style-linemove nav li:first-child.tab-current ~ li:last-child::before {
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(-400%,0,0);
 transform: translate3d(-400%,0,0);
}

.tabs-style-linemove nav li:nth-child(2).tab-current ~ li:last-child::before {
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(-300%,0,0);
 transform: translate3d(-300%,0,0);
}

.tabs-style-linemove nav li:nth-child(3).tab-current ~ li:last-child::before {
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(-200%,0,0);
 transform: translate3d(-200%,0,0);
}

.tabs-style-linemove nav li:nth-child(4).tab-current ~ li:last-child::before {
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%,0,0);
 transform: translate3d(-100%,0,0);
}

.tabs-style-linemove nav a {
 padding: 1em 0;
 color: #74777b;
 line-height: 1;
 -webkit-transition: color 0.3s, -webkit-transform 0.3s; 
 transition: color 0.3s, transform 0.3s;
}

.tabs-style-linemove nav li.tab-current a {
 color: #2CC185;
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,8px,0);
 transform: translate3d(0,8px,0);
}

.tabs-style-linemove nav a span {
 font-weight: 700;
}

/*****************************/
/* Line */
/*****************************/

.tabs-style-line nav ul {
 padding: 0 2em;
 max-width: none;
 box-shadow: inset 0 -2px #d1d3d2;
}

.tabs-style-line nav a {
 padding: 0.7em 0.4em;
 box-shadow: inset 0 -2px #d1d3d2;
 color: #74777b;
 text-align: left;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
 font-weight: 700;
 font-size: 0.8em;
 line-height: 1;
 -webkit-transition: color 0.3s, box-shadow 0.3s;
 transition: color 0.3s, box-shadow 0.3s;
}

.tabs-style-line nav a:hover,
.tabs-style-line nav a:focus {
 box-shadow: inset 0 -2px #74777b;
}

.tabs-style-line nav li.tab-current a {
 box-shadow: inset 0 -2px #2CC185;
 color: #2CC185;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 58em) {
 .tabs-style-line nav ul {
  display: block;
  box-shadow: none;
 }
 .tabs-style-line nav ul li {
  display: block;
  -webkit-flex: none;
  flex: none;
 }
}

/*****************************/
/* Circle */
/*****************************/

.tabs-style-circle {
 overflow: visible;
}

.tabs-style-circle nav li::before {
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 margin: -60px 0 0 -60px;
 width: 120px;
 height: 120px;
 border: 1px solid #2CC185;
 border-radius: 50%;
 content: '';
 opacity: 0;
 -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.2s, opacity 0.2s;
 transition: transform 0.2s, opacity 0.2s;
 -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.7,0,0.3,1);
 transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.7,0,0.3,1);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 58em) {
 .tabs-style-circle nav li::before {
  margin: -40px 0 0 -40px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
 }
}

.tabs-style-circle nav li.tab-current::before {
 opacity: 1;
 -webkit-transform: scale3d(1,1,1);
 transform: scale3d(1,1,1);
}

.tabs-style-circle nav a {
 overflow: visible;
 color: #74777b;
 font-weight: 700;
 font-size: 0.9em;
 line-height: 1.1;
 -webkit-transition: color 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.7,0,0.3,1); 
 transition: color 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.7,0,0.3,1);
}

.tabs-style-circle nav a span {
 display: inline-block;
}

.tabs-style-circle nav a span,
.tabs-style-circle .icon::before {
 -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.7,0,0.3,1);
 transition: transform 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.7,0,0.3,1);
}

.tabs-style-circle nav a:hover,
.tabs-style-circle nav a:focus {
 color: #4a4a4b;
}

.tabs-style-circle nav li.tab-current a {
 color: #2CC185;
}

.tabs-style-circle nav li.tab-current a span {
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,4px,0);
 transform: translate3d(0,4px,0);
}

.tabs-style-circle .icon::before {
 display: block;
 margin: 0;
 pointer-events: none;
}

.tabs-style-circle nav li.tab-current .icon::before {
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,-4px,0);
 transform: translate3d(0,-4px,0);
}

/*****************************/
/* Shape */
/*****************************/

.tabs-style-shape {
 max-width: 1200px;
}

.tabs-style-shape nav ul li {
 margin: 0 3em;
}

.tabs-style-shape nav ul li:first-child {
 margin-left: 0;
}

.tabs-style-shape nav ul li.tab-current {
 z-index: 100;
}

.tabs-style-shape nav li a {
 overflow: visible;
 margin: 0 -3em 0 0;
 padding: 0;
 color: #fff;
 font-weight: 500;
}

.tabs-style-shape nav li:first-child a span {
 padding-left: 2em;
 border-radius: 30px 0 0 0;
}

.tabs-style-shape nav li:last-child a span {
 padding-right: 2em;
 border-radius: 0 30px 0 0;
}

.tabs-style-shape nav li a svg {
 position: absolute;
 left: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 width: 3em;
 height: 100%;
 fill: #bdc2c9;
}

.tabs-style-shape nav li a svg:nth-child(2),
.tabs-style-shape nav li:last-child a svg {
 right: 100%;
 left: auto;
 -webkit-transform: scale3d(-1,1,1);
 transform: scale3d(-1,1,1);
}

.tabs-style-shape nav li a span {
 display: block;
 overflow: hidden;
 padding: 0.65em 0;
 background-color: #bdc2c9;
 text-overflow: ellipsis;
 white-space: nowrap;
}

.tabs-style-shape nav li a:hover span {
 background-color: #2CC185;
}

.tabs-style-shape nav li a:hover svg {
 fill: #2CC185;
}

/* Make only shape clickable */
.tabs-style-shape nav li a svg {
 pointer-events: none;
}

.tabs-style-shape nav li a svg use {
 pointer-events: auto;
}

.tabs-style-shape nav li.tab-current a span,
.tabs-style-shape nav li.tab-current a svg {
 -webkit-transition: none;
 transition: none;
}

.tabs-style-shape nav li.tab-current a span {
 background: #fff;
}

.tabs-style-shape nav li.tab-current a svg {
 fill: #fff;
}

.tabs-style-shape .content-wrap {
 background: #fff;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 58em) {
 .tabs-style-shape nav ul {
  display: block;
  padding-top: 1.5em;
 }
 .tabs-style-shape nav ul li {
  display: block;
  margin: -1.25em 0 0;
  -webkit-flex: none;
  flex: none;
 }
 .tabs-style-shape nav ul li a {
  margin: 0;
 }
 .tabs-style-shape nav ul li svg {
  display: none;
 }
 .tabs-style-shape nav ul li a span {
  padding: 1.25em 0 2em !important;
  border-radius: 30px 30px 0 0 !important;
  box-shadow: 0 -1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  line-height: 1;
 }
 .tabs-style-shape nav ul li:last-child a span {
  padding: 1.25em 0 !important;
 }
 .tabs-style-shape nav ul li.tab-current {
  z-index: 1;
 }
}

/*****************************/
/* Line Box */
/*****************************/

.tabs-style-linebox nav ul li {
 margin: 0 0.5em;
 -webkit-flex: none;
 flex: none;
}

.tabs-style-linebox nav a {
 padding: 0 1.5em;
 color: #74777b;
 font-weight: 700;
 -webkit-transition: color 0.3s;
 transition: color 0.3s;
}

.tabs-style-linebox nav a:hover,
.tabs-style-linebox nav a:focus {
 color: #2CC185;
}

.tabs-style-linebox nav li.tab-current a {
 color: #fff;
}

.tabs-style-linebox nav a::after {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 z-index: -1;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background: #d2d8d6;
 content: '';
 -webkit-transition: background-color 0.3s, -webkit-transform 0.3s;
 transition: background-color 0.3s, transform 0.3s;
 -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease, cubic-bezier(0.7,0,0.3,1);
 transition-timing-function: ease, cubic-bezier(0.7,0,0.3,1);
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,100%,0) translate3d(0,-3px,0);
 transform: translate3d(0,100%,0) translate3d(0,-3px,0);
}

.tabs-style-linebox nav li.tab-current a::after {
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
 transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}

.tabs-style-linebox nav a:hover::after,
.tabs-style-linebox nav a:focus::after,
.tabs-style-linebox nav li.tab-current a::after {
 background: #2CC185;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 58em) {
 .tabs-style-linebox nav ul {
  display: block;
  box-shadow: none;
 }
 .tabs-style-linebox nav ul li {
  display: block;
  -webkit-flex: none;
  flex: none;
 }
}

/*****************************/
/* Flip */
/*****************************/

.tabs-style-flip {
 max-width: 1200px;
}

.tabs-style-flip nav a {
 padding: 0.5em 0;
 color: #2CC185;
 -webkit-transition: color 0.3s;
 transition: color 0.3s;
}

.tabs-style-flip nav a:hover,
.tabs-style-flip nav a:focus,
.tabs-style-flip nav li.tab-current a {
 color: #74777b;
}

.tabs-style-flip nav a span {
 text-transform: uppercase;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
 font-weight: 700;
 font-size: 0.625em;
}

.tabs-style-flip nav a::after {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 z-index: -1;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background-color: #f0f0f0;
 content: '';
 -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s, background-color 0.3s;
 transition: transform 0.3s, background-color 0.3s;
 -webkit-transform: perspective(900px) rotate3d(1,0,0,90deg);
 transform: perspective(900px) rotate3d(1,0,0,90deg);
 -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
 transform-origin: 50% 100%;
 -webkit-perspective-origin: 50% 100%;
 perspective-origin: 50% 100%;
}

.tabs-style-flip nav li.tab-current a::after {
 background-color: #fff;
 -webkit-transform: perspective(900px) rotate3d(1,0,0,0deg);
 transform: perspective(900px) rotate3d(1,0,0,0deg);
}

.tabs-style-flip .content-wrap {
 background: #fff;
}


/*****************************/
/* Fill up */
/*****************************/

.tabs-style-fillup nav ul li a {
 padding: 1.9em 0;
 border-right: 1px solid #2CC185;
 line-height: 1;
 -webkit-transition: color 0.3s;
 transition: color 0.3s;
 -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
 backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.tabs-style-fillup nav ul li:last-child a {
 border: none;
}

.tabs-style-fillup nav ul li.tab-current {
 z-index: 100;
}

.tabs-style-fillup nav ul li.tab-current a {
 color: #fff;
}

.tabs-style-fillup nav ul li a::after {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 z-index: -1;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 height: calc(100% + 1px);
 border: 1px solid #2CC185;
 background: #2CC185;
 content: '';
 -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s;
 transition: transform 0.3s;
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,100%,0);
 transform: translate3d(0,100%,0);
}

.tabs-style-fillup nav ul li.tab-current a::after {
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
 transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}

.tabs-style-fillup nav ul li a span,
.tabs-style-fillup .icon::before {
 -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s;
 transition: transform 0.5s;
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,5px,0);
 transform: translate3d(0,5px,0);
}

.tabs-style-fillup nav ul li a span {
 display: block;
 font-weight: 700;
 font-size: 0.7em;
 line-height: 1.5;
}

.tabs-style-fillup .icon::before {
 display: block;
 margin: 0;
}

.tabs-style-fillup nav ul li.tab-current a span,
.tabs-style-fillup li.tab-current .icon::before {
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,-10px,0);
 transform: translate3d(0,-10px,0);
}


/*****************************/
/* Trapezoid, based on http://lea.verou.me/2013/10/slanted-tabs-with-css-3d-transforms/ */
/*****************************/ 

.tabs-style-tzoid {
 max-width: 1200px;
}

.tabs-style-tzoid nav {
 padding: 0 1em;
}

.tabs-style-tzoid nav ul li {
 -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
 backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.tabs-style-tzoid nav ul li a {
 padding: 0 1.5em 0 0.3em;
 color: #0d9564;
 -webkit-transition: color 0.2s;
 transition: color 0.2s;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 54em) {
 .tabs-style-tzoid nav ul li a {
  padding: 0 0.5em 0 0.3em;
 }
}

.tabs-style-tzoid nav ul li a:hover,
.tabs-style-tzoid nav ul li a:focus {
 color: #fff;
}

.tabs-style-tzoid nav ul li.tab-current a,
.tabs-style-tzoid nav ul li.tab-current a:hover {
 color: #2CC185;
}

.tabs-style-tzoid nav ul li a span {
 font-weight: 500;
 font-size: 0.75em;
}

.tabs-style-tzoid nav ul li a::after {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 z-index: -1;
 outline: 1px solid transparent;
 border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
 background: #2CC185;
 box-shadow: inset 0 -3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
 content: '';
 -webkit-transform: perspective(5px) rotateX(0.93deg) translateZ(-1px);
 transform: perspective(5px) rotateX(0.93deg) translateZ(-1px);
 -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
 transform-origin: 0 0;
 -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
 backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.tabs-style-tzoid nav ul li.tab-current a::after,
.tabs-style-tzoid .content-wrap {
 background: #fff;
 box-shadow: none;
}

/*****************************/
/* Circle fill */
/*****************************/

.tabs-style-circlefill {
 max-width: 700px;
 border: 1px solid #2CC185;
}

.tabs-style-circlefill nav ul li {
 overflow: hidden;
 border-right: 1px solid #2CC185;
}

.tabs-style-circlefill nav li a {
 padding: 1.5em 0;
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 1.25em;
}

.tabs-style-circlefill nav li:first-child {
 border-left: none;
}

.tabs-style-circlefill nav li:last-child {
 border: none;
}

.tabs-style-circlefill nav li::before {
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 margin: -40px 0 0 -40px;
 width: 80px;
 height: 80px;
 border: 1px solid #2CC185;
 border-radius: 50%;
 background: #2CC185;
 content: '';
 -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s;
 transition: transform 0.3s;
}

.tabs-style-circlefill nav li.tab-current::before {
 -webkit-transform: scale3d(2.5,2.5,1);
 transform: scale3d(2.5,2.5,1);
}

.tabs-style-circlefill nav a {
 -webkit-transition: color 0.3s; 
 transition: color 0.3s;
}

.tabs-style-circlefill nav a span {
 display: none;
}

.tabs-style-circlefill nav li.tab-current a {
 color: #fff;
}

.tabs-style-circlefill .icon::before {
 display: block;
 margin: 0;
 pointer-events: none;
}

.tabs-style-circlefill .content-wrap {
 border-top: 1px solid #2CC185;
}

/* Default tab style */

@font-face {
 font-weight: normal;
 font-style: normal;
 font-family: 'stroke7pixeden';
 src:url('../fonts/stroke7pixeden/stroke7pixeden.eot?u58ytb');
 src:url('../fonts/stroke7pixeden/stroke7pixeden.eot?#iefixu58ytb') format('embedded-opentype'),
  url('../fonts/stroke7pixeden/stroke7pixeden.woff?u58ytb') format('woff'),
  url('../fonts/stroke7pixeden/stroke7pixeden.ttf?u58ytb') format('truetype'),
  url('../fonts/stroke7pixeden/stroke7pixeden.svg?u58ytb#stroke7pixeden') format('svg');
}

.tabs {
 position: relative;
 overflow: hidden;
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 100%;
 font-weight: 300;
 font-size: 1.25em;
}

/* Nav */
.tabs nav {
 text-align: center;
  float: left;
}

.tabs nav ul {
 position: relative;
 display: -ms-flexbox;
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-flex;
 display: -ms-flex;
 display: flex;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 0;
 max-width: 1200px;
 list-style: none;
 -ms-box-orient: horizontal;
 -ms-box-pack: center;
 -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
 -moz-flex-flow: row wrap;
 -ms-flex-flow: row wrap;
 flex-flow: row wrap;
 -webkit-justify-content: center;
 -moz-justify-content: center;
 -ms-justify-content: center;
 justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.tabs nav ul li {
 position: relative;
 z-index: 1;
 display: block;
 margin: 0;
 text-align: center;
 -webkit-flex: 1;
 -moz-flex: 1;
 -ms-flex: 1;
 flex: 1;
}

.tabs nav a {
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 overflow: hidden;
 text-overflow: ellipsis;
 white-space: nowrap;
 line-height: 2.5;
}

.tabs nav a span {
 vertical-align: middle;
 font-size: 0.75em;
}

.tabs nav li.tab-current a {
 color: #74777b;
}

.tabs nav a:focus {
 outline: none;
}

/* Icons */
.icon::before {
 z-index: 10;
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 0 0.4em 0 0;
 vertical-align: middle;
 text-transform: none;
 font-weight: normal;
 font-variant: normal;
 font-size: 1.3em;
 font-family: 'stroke7pixeden';
 line-height: 1;
 speak: none;
 -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
 -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
 -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
.icon-upload::before {
 content: "\e68a";
}
.icon-tools::before {
 content: "\e60a";
}
.icon-plane::before {
 content: "\e625";
}
.icon-joy::before {
 content: "\e6a4";
}
.icon-plug::before {
 content: "\e69a";
}
.icon-home::before {
 content: "\e648";
}
.icon-gift::before {
 content: "\e652";
}
.icon-display::before {
 content: "\e65e";
}
.icon-date::before {
 content: "\e660";
}
.icon-config::before {
 content: "\e666";
}
.icon-coffee::before {
 content: "\e669";
}
.icon-camera::before {
 content: "\e66f";
}
.icon-box::before {
 content: "\e674";
}

/* Content */
.content-wrap {
 position: relative;
}

.content-wrap section {
 display: none;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 1em;
 max-width: 1200px;
 text-align: center;
}

.content-wrap section.content-current {
 display: block;
}

.content-wrap section p {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0.75em 0;
 color: rgba(40,44,42,0.05);
 font-weight: 900;
 font-size: 4em;
 line-height: 1;
}

/* Fallback */
.no-js .content-wrap section {
 display: block;
 padding-bottom: 2em;
 border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
}

.no-flexbox nav ul {
 display: block;
}

.no-flexbox nav ul li {
 min-width: 15%;
 display: inline-block;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 58em) {
 .tabs nav a.icon span {
  display: none;
 }
 .tabs nav a:before {
  margin-right: 0;
 }
}

@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,500,700);

@font-face {
 font-weight: normal;
 font-style: normal;
 font-family: 'codropsicons';
 src:url('../fonts/codropsicons/codropsicons.eot');
 src:url('../fonts/codropsicons/codropsicons.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
  url('../fonts/codropsicons/codropsicons.woff') format('woff'),
  url('../fonts/codropsicons/codropsicons.ttf') format('truetype'),
  url('../fonts/codropsicons/codropsicons.svg#codropsicons') format('svg');
}

*, *:after, *:before { -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box; }
.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after { content: ''; display: table; }
.clearfix:after { clear: both; }

body {
 background: #e7ecea;
 color: #74777b;
 font-weight: 400;
 font-size: 1em;
 font-family: 'Raleway', Arial, sans-serif;
}

a {
 color: #2CC185;
 text-decoration: none;
 outline: none;
}

a:hover, a:focus {
 color: #74777b;
}

.support {
 display: none;
 color: #ef5189;
 text-align: left;
 font-size: 1.5em;
 max-width: 1200px;
 margin: 1em auto 0;
 padding: 0;
}

.no-flexbox .support {
 display: block;
}

.hidden {
 position: absolute;
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
 opacity: 0;
}

.container > section {
 padding: 5em 0;
 font-size: 1.25em;
 min-height: 100%;
}

p {
 text-align: center;
 padding: 1em;
}

/* Header */
.codrops-header {
 padding: 7em 0 3em;
 letter-spacing: -1px;
}

.codrops-header h1 {
 max-width: 1200px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 font-weight: 800;
 font-size: 5em;
 line-height: 1;
}

.codrops-header h1 span {
 display: block;
 font-size: 50%;
 font-weight: 400;
 padding-top: 0.325em;
 color: #bdc2c9;
}

/* To Navigation Style */
.codrops-top {
 width: 100%;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-weight: 700;
 font-size: 0.69em;
 line-height: 2.2;
}

.codrops-top a {
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 1em 2em;
 text-decoration: none;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.codrops-top span.right {
 float: right;
}

.codrops-top span.right a {
 display: block;
 float: left;
}

.codrops-icon:before {
 margin: 0 4px;
 text-transform: none;
 font-weight: normal;
 font-style: normal;
 font-variant: normal;
 font-family: 'codropsicons';
 line-height: 1;
 speak: none;
 -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

.codrops-icon-drop:before {
 content: "\e001";
}

.codrops-icon-prev:before {
 content: "\e004";
}

/* Related demos */
.related {
 text-align: center;
}

.related > a {
 width: calc(100% - 20px);
 max-width: 340px;
 border: 1px solid black;
 border-color: initial;
 display: inline-block;
 text-align: center;
 margin: 20px 10px;
 padding: 25px;
}

.related a img {
 max-width: 100%;
 opacity: 0.8;
}

.related a:hover img,
.related a:active img {
 opacity: 1;
}

.related a h3 {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0.5em 0 0.3em;
 max-width: 300px;
 text-align: left;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1280px) {
 .codrops-header h1 {
  padding: 0 0.5em;
 }
 .support {
  padding: 0 1.5em;
 }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 30em) {
 .container > section {
  padding: 3em 0;
 }
 .codrops-header {
  padding: 2em 0 1em;
 }
 .codrops-header h1 {
  font-size: 3.5em;
 }
}


@media screen and (max-width: 25em) {
 .codrops-icon {
  font-size: 1.5em;
 }
 .codrops-icon span {
  display: none;
 }
}
```

```html
<div style="height: 100vh; width: 100vw">
 <div style="height:97%; width: 100%; border:2px yellow solid">
  <section>
   <div class="tabs tabs-style-iconbox" style=" border:2px blue solid; height:24em">
    <nav>
     <ul>
      <li><a href="#section-iconbox-1" class="icon icon-home"><span>Home</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#section-iconbox-2" class="icon icon-gift"><span>Deals</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#section-iconbox-3" class="icon icon-upload"><span>Local</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#section-iconbox-4" class="icon icon-coffee"><span>New York</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#section-iconbox-5" class="icon icon-config"><span>Genius</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#section-iconbox-5" class="icon icon-config"><span>Exclusives</span></a></li>
     </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="content-wrap">
     <section id="section-iconbox-1" style="border:2px red solid; height: 17em"><p style="border:2px green solid; height: 3.9em"></p></section>
     <section id="section-iconbox-2"><p>2</p></section>
     <section id="section-iconbox-3"><p>3</p></section>
     <section id="section-iconbox-4"><p>4</p></section>
     <section id="section-iconbox-5"><p>5</p></section>
    </div><!-- /content -->
   </div><!-- /tabs -->
  </section>

  </div>
 </div><!-- /container -->
 <script src="js/cbpFWTabs.js"></script>
 <script>
  (function() {

   [].slice.call( document.querySelectorAll( '.tabs' ) ).forEach( function( el ) {
    new CBPFWTabs( el );
   });

  })();
 </script>
```